# SharePoint Global Navigation issue, the subsite does not show in Navigation setting

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, global-navigation

I have a sub-site off of a sub-site and want to hide it in the `Global Navigation` (which is inheriting from the Parent site) but it is not showing in the Navigation setting list in the parent site for me to hide. But it is still showing in the Navigation.

**For example:**

- **Parent Site** - sub-sub-site does not show in Navigation setting list for me to hide but shows on the Global Navigation.
- **Sub-site** - inheriting Navigation from the Parent site.
  **Sub-sub-site** - inheriting global navigation from the Parent site.

Answer (score 2):

**First,** you should be aware of the navigation setting for the parent site shows only the sub sites in **Level 1**

---

**[For Example]**

You have **Top Level Site** > `Sub Site1` > `Sub Site2`

- So in `Top Level Site` navigation setting, you will only find `Sub Sie1`.
- And in `Sub Sie1` navigation setting, you will only find `Sub Sie2`.

**So** to hide `Sub Site2` from the `Global Navigation` you should do this in the `Sub Sie1` navigation setting, **not** in `Top Level Site` navigation setting.